# sharepoint hosted app will be access all document libraries in a SharePoint farm

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-hosted-app

Which authentication method suitable for SharePoint hosted app will be access all document libraries in a sharepoint farm

1- Use the SharePoint server-to-server security token service (STS).

or

2 Use the Open Authorization 2.0 (OAuth 2.0) web authorization protocol.